# Creating a remote control mobile app

Tags: ios, windows, macos, swift, ios8

I'd like to go about creating a mobile app that works as a remote control. Nothing too complex. Just something, for example, to control the system's volume.

However, I have no idea on how to go about making such an app as not only would it require me to develop for the phone platform but also for the PC/Mac platform. Any inputs, on where I should start looking or go about making such an app, would be appreciated.

FYI: I'm interested in making an iOS app using Swift that works with Mac/PC. I'm currently taking a course to learn iOS app development in Swift.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an IR led to do this, and the iPhone don't have it. Try with something different, if you want to use sensors here is a list of sensors available on the iPhone for developers:

iphone 5, 5S, 5C
 - Proximity sensor
 - Accelerometer
 - Magnetometer
 - Gyroscope
 - Touch Screen
 - Camera

iphone 6

- Barometer

Edit:

If you know enough about electronics, you can control an IR led with the headphone output. (Analog) I'm sure theres more information about doing this in google.